# Signal Trapping in bash works only once in RHEL7 (but not in Ubuntu)

Tags: bash, unix, signals, rhel

I have run into a strange (and probably platform specific issue) when attempting to do a trap-sleep loop.

Specifically, the following code:

```
saysomething() {
    trap saysomething 37
    echo "Hello there"
    while true; do
        sleep 1
    done
}

echo "Current pid: $$"
saysomething
```

prints "Hello there" everytime I send it a signal from another shell using `kill -37 <pid>` on Ubuntu 14.04.

However, on an RHEL 7 machine, the above prints `Hello there` the first time only. After that, the script keeps executing but fails to respond to any more signals.

What could be the reason for this difference?

Comment: sorry! read too fast. maybe you could do it from outside the function, then.

Comment: Are you using the same version of `bash` on both machines?

Comment: No. Looks like the `bash` versions are different. 4.3.11 on Ubuntu and 4.2.46 on RHEL 7. Would that lead to such a stark difference in behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but this is the workaround I ended up using the following as a workaround:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

flag=false

saysomething() {
    flag=true   
    trap reset 37
    echo "Hello there"
    while [[ $flag == true ]]; do
        sleep 1
    done
    saysomething
}

reset() {
    flag=false
}

echo "Current pid: $$"

saysomething
```

I still can't explain the reason for this difference in behaviour though.